# RS485 not working

Tags: arduino, rs485, arduino-uno

I want to send data between different Arduinos distributed in different places:
Something like this: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-master-slave-communication-using-rs485-and-modbus-protocol/644168

[image]

I created my own Arduino shield based on this RS485 board:

[image]

When I connect two Arduinos using two of these boards, I can send data from one to the other. But when I use at least one of mine, nothing happens.

I checked:

- cables.
- power in the RS485 with multimeter.
- pins matching Arduino to Shield.
- Disconnecting the GND between the boards as my circuit has R28 and C22 that are not in the original board.
- Connecting the GND of the Arduinos togheter.

I don't know what else I can do. I saw R25 and R27 can be smaller.  Any suggestions? Should I remove R28 and C22? Should I reduce R25 and R27?

This is how my schematic:

[image]

---

**SOLUTION**

When designing the schematic, I crossed by mistake A and B and it is mentioned in [@MF3 answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/266745/mf3). With this error, R25 and R27 are pulling up and down the lines in the wrong way and it is not working. After removing them, I can connect my shield and one of the boards mentioned without any problem.

The current configuration is:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Could you say a) how long are the cables, and b) what is the grounding between the various units?  Those modules aren't very good because they ahve no connection for ground,s and RS-485 requires ground.

Comment: I want to connect them with a 10 m cable. But I am using a short one now. What do you mean by grounding?

Comment: Jonathan means the grounds on all the boards need to be connected together

Comment: So I should connect the GND between the Arduinos, correct?

Comment: I just tried it, and it is not working. The post was updated. Thanks!

Comment: @jonathanjo That is not true. Maxim and some other chip manufacturers use A for non-inverting pin and RS-485 standard uses A for inverting pin.

Comment: @justme of course you're right about the terminology.  Deleted, recommented.

Comment: Yes, but more importantly connect all the D+ to D+ and D- to D-  throughout. It's not like RS-232 where you need swapping anywhere. I also strongly recommend reading Bob Perrrin's indispensible [Art and Science of RS-485](https://www2.htw-dresden.de/%7Ehuhle/ArtScienceRS485.pdf), especially the portions about grounding.  See MF3's answer about which lines are pulled up and which are pulled down.

Comment: @jonathanjo thanks ! I followed the what is mentioned in the answer you cited and it works after removing the pull up and pull down in the boards.

Comment: All of the things mentioned were causing the problem; not the last thing. You appear to think that you when swapped the A and B lines and, it began working that all the previous things you tried were not to blame but, they are.

Comment: I strongly recommend you label your circuit with D+ and D- (or DPOS and DNEG) for the reason that use of A and B is very confusingly used through the industry.  See eg (Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485#Signals) about the confusion.

Comment: ......In other words, your edited section (that explains where you thought you were wrong) is totally misleading and, in effect, also wrong. Please don't try and answer in your question until you fully understand the implications of what you write. For that reason I felt compelled to downvote your question. This can be removed once you remove the erroneous edited section.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in your schematic:

- **A and B are crossed**: The terminal A is connected to the pin B (pin 7 or the MAX485E) and the terminal B is connected to pin A (pin 6 or the MAX485E).
- **The fail-safe biasing circuit is wrong**: The resistor connected to the pin B (R25) should be a pull-down and it is pull-up. Something similar happens to the pin A, as the R27 shoul be pull-up and it pull-down. This capture may help:
  [image]

***Reference**: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an-960.pdf*

Regarding the values of R25 and R27, the same link shows you how to obtain them.

I think you should remove the two resistors mentioned (R25 and R27) from the boards, and then wired the boards considering that all the pin B are connected togheter and the same with pin A.
One last thing, you should have only two terminator resistors (R26) and in your circuit, it looks like they are always there, so if you connect more than 2 boards, you should remove one.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. That is not true. Maxim and some other chip manufacturers use A for non-inverting pin and RS-485 standard uses A for inverting pin.

Comment: So I should remove R25 and R27 from all my shields and then connect to the same letter as  @jonathanjo mentioned before. As I am testing with two boards, I should keep R26. Correct me if I am wrong, please!

Comment: It works! So the problem is R25 and R27.

Answer (score 0):

If all nodes have biasing and termination resistors, it will not work.

Only the two devices at the ends of the bus should have the terminations present. Not all. And the biasing resistors should be present only once on the bus.

Also RS-485 is not a two-wire bus, as the devices must share a common ground reference. Your design does not connect grounds between RS-485 boards. So if the are powered from different, unrelated power sources, there may be too much voltage between grounds and RS-485 will not work.

Comment: "and RS-485 will not work" ... indeed, I often find transceivers are destroyed on site by exactly this, and hence I normally recommend through-hole DIL chips with sockets.